# Django - Problemas em salvar objectos com ID do tipo UUID no admin

Tags: python, django, uuid

Trabalho em um projecto em **Python com Framework Django** e recentemente decidimos alterar a geracao dos IDs de **inteiro para UUID** por motivos de *merge* dos dados antes da sincronizacao (temos dados que chegam de bases diferentes e precisam ser agregados numa base central). Todas a nossas entidades foram alteradas conforme o exemplo abaixo (segundo a documentacao consultada)

```html
class TestModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4(), editable=False, auto_created=True)
    test_name = models.TextField("Test Name", blank=True)
    test_surname = models.TextField("Test Surname", blank=True)
```

Apos esta alteracao so é possivel inserir dados directo pela base de dados e pelo admin ja nao é posssivel embora a messagem de sucesso continua a ser apresentado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muita luta descobri o problema. Eu estava a colocar o default para o UUIDField desta forma

```js
default=uuid.uuid4()
```

quando deve ser assim

```js
default=uuid.uuid4
```

Se repararem a diferença esta nos parenteses. Colocando parenteses significa chamada de um metodo e quando esta sem parenteses é referencia ao metodo. Resumindo, sempre que o servidor arranca a primeira vez que um objecto é criado o metodo e chamado e o seu valor guardado na cache e nas proximas chamadas ele usa o mesmo valor gerado de uuid. Trocando para referencia garante-se que sempre que um objecto é o metodo é sempre chamdo.

Fica a dica para todos